# Send email in R with attachment

Tags: r

Any idea how I would add an attachment to this email?

I tried to look at names(OutApp) to see if there was an "attachment" that I could assign to but there doesn't seem to be. Any ideas?

```
library(RDCOMClient)

SendEmail<-function(to, subject, body)
{
  ## init com api
  OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
  ## create an email 
  outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
  ## configure  email parameter 
  outMail[["To"]] = "me@me.com"
  outMail[["subject"]] = subject
  outMail[["body"]] = body

  ## send it                     
  outMail$Send()

}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at sendmailR [here](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/building-email-reports-with-r.html)?